# How to use mocks in Scala to mock a singleton object

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I recently started programming in Scala. I have a project with a hierarchy of classes that call each other. Eventually, they last one calls a singleton DAL (Data Access Layer) object that calls a stored procedure in MySQL.

I have a DAL object with the following signature:

`def callStoredProcedure(procName: String, params: Array[String]): Boolean`

I'd like to write a test that calls a function of the top level class, and checks out what `procName` was passed to the function.

How do I go about creating a mock for the DAL object? How can I inject it into the process pipeline, or is there a better/recommended way to replace the singleton with a mock that just returns the procedure name rather than calling it?

We're currently using Mockito, but I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use singletons directly, that's not a good idea. You know why? Because you can't mock them for unit testing, duh.
Make it a parameter to your class instead:

```
trait DAL {
  def callStoredProcedure(procName: String, params: Array[String]): Boolean       
}

object DALImpl extends DAL {
    def callStoredProcedure(procName: String, params: Array[String]): Boolean = doStuff
}

class Foo(dal: DAL = DALImpl) 

val testMe = new Foo(mock[DAL])
```

or

```
class Foo {
    def dal: DAL = DALImpl
}

val testMe = new Foo {
  override def dal = mock[DAL]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
class Foo(dal: DAL)

val testMe = new Foo(dal = mock[DAL.type])
```

Cheers

Comment: How does that help, if I may ask? I want to grab the stored proc's name, without it being actually called. Spying won't do that. Mocking would still require an injection through all layers. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes indeed `mock[DAL.type]` will require injection just like Dima showed you but without having to bother with a trait. `spy(DAL)` is actually not relevant for you as it will actually compute the function. I edit my answer.